# Difference between merge and create in Cypher

Tags: neo4j

1. Could anyone please tell me the difference between Merge and Create in Cypher Querying.
2. How Neo4j stores data physically?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CREATE` does just what it says.  It creates, and if that means creating duplicates, well then it creates.   `MERGE` does the same thing as create, but also checks to see if a node already exists with the properties you specify.  If it does, then it doesn't create.  This helps avoid duplicates.   Here's an example: I use `CREATE` twice to create a person with the same name.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ create (p:Person {name: "Bob"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
9 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ create (p:Person {name: "Bob"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
5 ms
```

So now when we query, there are two Bob's.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (p:Person {name:"Bob"}) return p;
+--------------------------+
| p                        |
+--------------------------+
| Node[222124]{name:"Bob"} |
| Node[222125]{name:"Bob"} |
+--------------------------+
2 rows
46 ms
```

Let's `MERGE` in another Bob and see what happens.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ merge (p:Person {name:"Bob"});
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
2 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (p:Person {name:"Bob"}) return p;
+--------------------------+
| p                        |
+--------------------------+
| Node[222124]{name:"Bob"} |
| Node[222125]{name:"Bob"} |
+--------------------------+
2 rows
11 ms
```

Bob already existed, so `MERGE` did nothing here.  Querying again, the same two Bobs are present.   Had there been no Bobs in the database, `MERGE` would have done the same thing as `CREATE`.